# Представление (view) в Yii

Tags: php, yii

Две строчки кода в Yii.
Как чекбокс окружить тегом <label> и вывести свой текст? (сейчас в label выводиться 'Only Crash') ???

```
<div class="form">
    <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>
    <?php print $form->errorSummary($eventDateForm); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Укажите временной интервал</label>
        <label>
        С <?php print $form->textField($eventDateForm, 'eventPeriodBegin', array('value' => date("d-m-Y"), 'class' => 'span1')); ?>
        По <?php print $form->textField($eventDateForm, 'eventPeriodEnd', array('value' => date("d-m-Y"), 'class' => 'span1')); ?>
        </label>
        <?php print $form->checkBox($eventDateForm, 'onlyCrash', array('value' => TRUE, 'class' => 'span1'))?>
        <?php print $form->label($eventDateForm, 'onlyCrash'); ?>
    </div>    
    <div class="row submit">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Показать события на объекте'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

В мануале не нашёл.

**UPDATE** весь код виджета выше

Comment: Зачем окружать чекбокс тегом label? Какой пакет используется, CHtml или CActiveForm?

Comment: красоты ради. Буквально: хочу что бы чекбокс и его описание были на одной строке.

Comment: Ну так это решается с помощью CSS. А описание полей CActiveForm берет из модели.

Comment: @Zhukov Roman Не согласен с вами. текст лэбла берётся из второго параметра.

Код:

    <?php print $form->label($eventDateForm, 'onlyCrash'); ?>

выплюнет html:  

    <label for="EventForm_onlyCrashText">Only Crash</label>

Аналогично:  

    <?php print $form->label($eventDateForm, 'тупо текст'); ?>

Выдаст:  

    <label for="EventForm_топо_текст">топо текст</label>

мне же нужно, что бы у лэбла атрибут for был на мой чексбокс и текст другой, а не название.

Comment: С текстом сам разобрался:

    <?php print $form->label($eventDateForm, 'мой текст',array('for'=>'onlyCrash')); ?>

Указываем for в списке дополнительных опций.

    <label for="onlyCrash">мой текст</label>

Теперь осталось придумать как теперь окружить мой чекбокс именно этим лэблом

Comment: for не нужен, если input единственный и внутри label, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/label при этом сам label может содержать любые тэги, с исключением "No labelable elements other than the labeled control are allowed."

Comment: @eicto перечитайте мой вопрос или коммент перед вашим.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'points_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->checkboxlist($model, 'points_id', points::model()->getPoints());?>    
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'points_id'); ?>
</div>
```

Делаешь просто див, хотя он в базовой форме всегда есть, и выводишь лейбл. и Роман правильно заметил чем пользуешься. Все от этого зависит.

Comment: Ну, судя по параметрам, у него CActiveForm. Я просто давно не трогал Yii, подзабыл.

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема, дописать тег <label>??

Comment: @Shrek только в том что хочется через api :)

Comment: Я уже написал пример в ответе.

Comment: в манах нет метода getPoints()  
Что он делает?

Comment: В манах, к сведению, нет ни одной моей модели, контроллера и вьюшки.

Пример - это краткое описание того что можно сделать.

>points::model()->getPoints()

Это моя модель, которая что-то получает. Ну подумать то немного... ну капельку.

Answer (score 0):

не темплейт ли имеется ввиду?

```
 echo CHtml::checkBox('im_id2', array(), array(
     'template' => '{input} {labelTitle}',                
 ));
```